# Chinese characters are not displayed properly in asp net core razor account page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core

I am working on my first website project. I pick the asp net core 2.0 and
I got a problem. After creating the project from the template, I change some title string to Chinese (such as the index.cshtml at the root fold), and things work well. But if I change the title string in the `/page/account/manage/login.cshtml`, the title does not display the right way:

[image]

The Chinese in the green box is right, while those login & register Chinese in the red box is not displayed properly. Any idea how this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: probably you need to set the encoding of your html page properly

Comment: So what have you done to diagnose the problem so far? Where does the incorrect data come from? Have you worked out at what stage it becomes invalid? The correct characters in green suggests that this *isn't* an encoding issue at the HTML level, but instead a problem in terms of getting the right string to Razor.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I did not do much to change to title, and I did not change the underlying code to display the strings. Ijust change the 
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in" to  ViewData["Title"] = "登录", which has the same meaning between Chinese and English， I did the same way for the string in the green box, nothing more.

Comment: So have you tried setting a breakpoint and looking at the string in a debugger?

Comment: I wonder whether the character encoding for the cshtml file is correct when OP saved it. ViewData is a dictionary of strings, right? Perhaps the compiler isn't reading the string "登录" correctly, or whether it's being stored on disk (before being read by the compiler) correctly.

Comment: Hi, @JamieTaylor you are right, the files for the string displayed in the green box are in "UTF-8" format, while those not displayed properly are in ANSI format, thanks very much , problem fixed! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by @Jamie Taylor, I checked all the *.cshtml files that not being displayed properly, and found their format were "ANSI", I Open them with windows textpad and save them as "UTF-8" format, now things got fixed.

Thanks to Jamie.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help